# Angular 2+ Error - Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("-group">

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

i am using Angular 2+ forms.

Error in details : 
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("-group">
    First Name
    ]#firstName = "ngModel" (change) ="log(firstName)" id="firstName"  class="form-control">
    )
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)

Below is my contact-form.component.html page :

```
   <form>
         <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input required ngModel name="firstName" #firstName = "ngModel" (change) ="log(firstName)" id="firstName"  class="form-control">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = "!firstName.valid">First Name is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea ngModel name ="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

below is my contact-form.component.ts page  : 




import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'contact-form',
      templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactFormComponent {

      log(x) {
      console.log(x);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Show us your `app.module.ts` or the module you have defined

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
import { SummaryPipe } from './summary.pipe';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel.component';
import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    SummaryPipe,
    PanelComponent,
    InputFormatDirective,
    ContactFormComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
    
  ],
  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are mixing both forms approaches. Instead of this:

```
<input required ngModel name="firstName" #firstName = "ngModel" (change)="log(firstName)" id="firstName"  class="form-control">
```

I'd suggest to try (assuming you create a `firstName` property in `ContactFormComponent`):

```
<input required [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control">
```